# Not able to extract the certificate for elasticsearch cluster transport layer hosted on AKS

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, kubectl, azure-aks

I have a elasticsearch cluster running on Azure AKS. I want to connect to a different es cluster running on seperate AKS for which I need to export certificate from one cluster and add it to the other cluster. I am following the official documentation from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-remote-clusters.html)
.
However I am not able to export the certificate and getting error on executing the following command:

> kubectl get secret europecluster-es-transport-certs-public -o
> go-template='{{index .data "ca.crt"}}'

Error I am getting is:

```
error: error parsing template {{index .data ca.crt}}, template: output:1: function "ca" not defined
```

I am novice in elastic and kubernetes space, and not able to find solution for this on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go and get the certificate.

```
kubectl get secret elasticsearch-master-certificate -o go-template='{{index .data "ca.crt" | base64decode }}' > /path/ca.crt

kubectl get secret elasticsearch-master-certificate -o go-template='{{index .data "tls.crt" | base64decode }}' > /path/tls.crt

kubectl get secret elasticsearch-master-certificate -o go-template='{{index .data "tls.key" | base64decode }}' > /path/tls.key
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay to manually extract the ca.crt value and decode it then you can try following:

1. Extract ca.crt value without quotes [copy to clipboard]

`kubectl get secret europecluster-es-transport-certs-public | grep ca.crt`

2. perform a base64decode and redirect it to a file

`echo -n <paste clipboard content> | base64 -d -w 0 > remote.ca.crt`

Above procedure performs same operation as go template is doing in your command.

Example:

```
 kubectl get secret default-token-h8w57 -o json | grep -i ca.crt
        "ca.crt": "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"


 echo -n 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 | base64 -d -w 0 > remote.ca.crt
```